# Is it possible to extract only number from a string

Tags: java

I am doing data scrap on a website using Jsoup and the response I am getting from the server is below

```
Prev. Close: 65.113
```

My question is  is it possible to extract only **65.113** ??

I cannot use replace as the text might change

Comment: you can use split function or go for regex.

Comment: There's not enough information here to give anywhere near a sensible answer. If the text might change, what do you know will _always_ be constant, therefore are able to strip out? Which aspects might change? Do you have lots of examples? It's easy enough to give an example for what you've posted, but there's no way anyone can post a reasonable answer if all you've said is "the text might change"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have exact format

```
String input = "Prev. Close: 65.113";
String result = input.split(":")[1].trim();
```

Will give you the result.

Comment: @Kiran - Just ensure that you don't have some data following your number :)

Comment: If you do decide to use this, watch out for anomalies if the server returns unexpected values.  For example, if you don't get a `:` in the response, you'll end up with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  Or if there's a `:` in a different place (e.g., earlier in the text part), you might get errors, too.  A regex will ensure you extract numerical data.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to make use of a regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\.\d+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Prev. Close: 65.113");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: @tobias_k now I think it's ok. Don't you think ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex : Works for all negative cases as well

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Prev. Close: 65.113";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
65.113
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
String str = "Prev. Close: 65.113";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(m.group(0));
}
```